# Cloudberry Backup Inherit Backup State

Tags: backup, cloudberry

Is there a way to "inherit" an existing backup state on a new computer? Use case is that a computer is reinstalled, and data is backed up and restored using a local USB drive. Can a previous backup location be inherited so that the entire backup process doesn't need to be restarted?

Answer (score 0):

For sure that is possible.
Please, add your previous storage account, go to it's settings->advanced settings and change your prefix to the previous one (it's a machine name). After that, the sync would commence and you will be able to backup from the point you've stopped previously.